# Conversion function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I need to execute a function that converts 2 characters to an integer.

The rule works this way:

```
99 = 99
9A = 100
9B = 101
9C = 102
9D = 103
.
.
.
9Z = 125
AA = 126
AB = 127
```

So for example, my function receives '9C' and should return '102'. The function must be done in SQL.

This is just an example, the sequence exists has all the characters of the alphabet and the number from 0 to 9.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  What have you tried that is not working?  This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Executing a function is really easy.  You can do `select dbo.my_func('9A')` for example.

Comment: @Rafaela you have only values listed above or do you have more (apart from 9E to 9Y)?

Comment: The numbering here seems weird. If 99 = 99 then, I assume, that 90 = 90.following your logic, therefore, what does 8Z and 89 equal? 89 and 63 respectively maybe? That would get really weird, in my view, when you get to around 0. One would expect 0 = 0, but this wouldn't be the case here.

Comment: @RaghuParvatha, The sequence has all combinations, from 00 to ZZ

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: So, what are the values of `00` and `ZZ` in decimal? Make sure you include that in your post, alongside what you tried already.

Comment: I was guessing it was char and ZZ would be 801 @Larnu but tricky for sure. I don't know why it started at 9, but if it could go to 8 like you suggested I think it's impossible. I based it off the sequence

Comment: Touché @GordonLinoff  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to turn a base36 number into a base10 number.

Then you could create a function for base conversion.

**The function**

```
create function dbo.fnBase36ToBase10(@input varchar(8))
returns int
as
begin
  declare @base36string varchar(8) = upper(@input);
  declare @result int = 0;
  declare @basechars varchar(36) = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  declare @N int = 36;
  declare @digit char(1);
  declare @pow int = 0;

  while @pow < len(@base36string)
  begin
    set @Digit = substring(reverse(@base36string),@Pow+1,1);
    set @result = @result + (charindex(@Digit, @basechars)-1) * power(@N, @pow);
    set @pow = @pow + 1;
  end
  return @result;
end;
GO
```

**Example using the function**

```
select code, (dbo.fnBase36ToBase10(code) - 234) as num
from (values
 ('99'),('9A'),('9B'),('9C')
,('9Z'),('A0')
,('A9'),('AA'),('AB')
) AS codes(code)
order by num;
```

**Returns:**

```
code    num
99      99
9A      100
9B      101
9C      102
9Z      125
A0      126
A9      135
AA      136
AB      137
```

And if creating a function isn't an option.
Then you could join to a Tally Table that contains the conversion between the 
Base36 and Base10 numbers.

**Example:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Base36ToBase10') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Base36ToBase10;
CREATE TABLE #Base36ToBase10 (base36 varchar(2) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS primary key, base10 int);

-- Fill Tally Table
;WITH CHARS AS 
(
    select 0 as n, convert(char(1),0) as c 
    union all 
    select n+1, iif(n<9,convert(char(1),n+1),char(n+56)) 
    from CHARS where n < 35
)
insert into #Base36ToBase10 (base36, base10)
select 
 concat(c2.c,c1.c) as b36, 
 (c2.n*36+c1.n) as b10
from CHARS c1
cross join CHARS c2
order by c2.c, c1.c;

declare @codes table (code varchar(2));
insert into @codes (code) values
 ('99'),('9A'),('9B'),('9C')
,('9Z'),('A0')
,('A9'),('AA'),('AB')
;

select code, (b36to10.base10 - 234) as num
from @codes AS codes
join #Base36ToBase10 as b36to10 
  on codes.code collate Latin1_General_CS_AS = b36to10.base36
order by num;
```

Comment: @Rafaela Cool. So just out of curiosity, which method of the 2 would you use?  Btw, if this is correct you might wanna change those expected results in your question. F.e. the number of 'AA' is different. (and I substracted 234 just to return 99 for code '99' to match those expected results)

Answer (score 0):

This was fun and tricky. I used a tally table to build out the ASCII table and apply a `dense_rank` and `row_number` to the unique characters, and character pairs. Then, the result is a trivial `case` statement.

```
declare @val varchar(2) = '9C'

;WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )

select
    RN = dense_rank() over (order by c.N)
    ,d = char(c.N)
    ,d2 = char(c.N) + char(c2.N)
    ,RN2 = row_number() over (order by c.N, c2.N) + 125
into #myTemp
from cteTally c
cross apply cteTally c2
where c.N between 65 and 90 and c2.N between 65 and 90

--uncomment this code to see how the ranking and row_number worked
--select * 
--from #myTemp
--order by RN

select
    case 
        when @val like '[0-9][0-9]' then @val
        when @val like '[9][A-Z]' then 99 + (select top 1 RN  from #myTemp where d = right(@val,1))
        when @val like '[A-Z][A-Z]' then (select RN2 from #myTemp where d2 = @val)
    end

drop table #myTemp
```

Comment: Your function was working too, congrats, and thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks @Rafaela it was the first answer :) and is faster than the recursive cte and function in the accepted answer